# Regex pattern that will not match the brackets at the end of the string

Tags: c#, regex

From a large list of text I want to get only these lines:

```
Ks 2 ... No brackets at the end!
Ks 2 ... (/R)
```

So from an example as below:

```
Ks 2 an wo co lo
Ks 2 ni ta ko shi (/R)
Ks 2 fa ki de so (R)
Ks 1 ha lo pa
```

Pattern should match:

```
Ks 2 an wo co lo
Ks 2 ni ta ko shi (/R)
```

I have tried to create something like this: `Ks 2(.*)\(\/R\)|Ks 2(.*)(^(\(\/R\))$`

Can anyone help me how to create this pattern ?!

Comment: so the decisive elements are the `2` and the `(/R)` ? the middle part is not important ?=!

Comment: @MongZhu `Ks 2` and `(/R)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^Ks 2.*(?:\(/R\)|[^)])$
^Ks 2.*(?:\(/R\)|(?<!\)))$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TwOrbK/1) (or [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/TwOrbK/2)).

*Note*: If you deal with multiline texts, add `\r?` before `$` and add `(?m)` at the start of the pattern. Also, replace `[^)]` with `[^)\n]` in the first pattern. E.g. `(?m)^Ks 2.*(?:\(/R\)|[^)\r\n])\r?$` and `(?m)^Ks 2.*(?:\(/R\)|(?<!\)\r?))\r?$`.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a string
- `Ks 2` - a fixed string
- `.*`  - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `(?:\(/R\)|[^)])` - either `(/R)` or a char other than `)`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: The pattern matches the line even when (/ R) is in the middle of the line, can you help me please, the pattern should match the line only if (/ R) is at the end of it!

Comment: @kn1ghtxx `Ks 2 n (/ R) end` matches because as you say it starts with `Ks 2` and does not end with `)`. What is the additional restriction then? If there is no `)` at the end AND no `(/ R)` anywhere in the string? Like in `^Ks 2.*(?:\(/\s*R\)|[^)\n](?<!\(/\s*R\).*))$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/TwOrbK/3))?